# With Rust how do I perform a common set of actions on functions that return different types

Tags: rust

I'm a bit of a Rust newbie, so please go easy on me!

I'm trying to write a simple application that generates fake tabular data based on a simple list of column types.

For example have functions that create fake names & ages:

```
fn name() -> String {
    FirstName(EN).fake()
}

fn age() -> i64 {
    rand::thread_rng().gen_range(0, 100)
}
```

However, I'm struggling with the type-system when trying to use these functions to generate data based on what will eventually be a dynamically provided list of types:

```
pub fn generate()  {
    let generators = vec!["age", "name"];

    // generate each row
    for _ in 1..10 {
        // generate a value of the given type
        for gen_type in generators.iter() {
            // error[E0308]: match arms have incompatible types
            let generator = match gen_type.as_ref() {
                "age" => age,
                "name" => name,
                _ => println!("Error"),
            };

            let out = generator();

            // eventually I'll want to add some further logic here

            println!("{}", out);
        }
    }
}
```

I understand the issue, the `generator` variable needs to have a static type, but am unsure how I can proceed?

Should I encapsulate `String` and `i64` within a generic struct? Or can I use `Box` somehow? Once again, apologies for the vague question - a pointer (no pun intended) in the right direction would be appreciated!

Comment: You're probably better off putting all of the logic in the match arms so you can do type-specific things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, you want polymorphism.

In Rust, you have the choice between two different mechanisms:

- Enums: a closed set of possibilities.
- Traits: an open set of possibilities.

Traits are more generic (!), at the cost of being a bit more complex; in general when both can be used, I would recommend enums.

---

Let's apply this to your problem:

```
enum Property {
    Age(i64),
    Name(String),
}

fn name() -> Property {
    Property::Name(FirstName(EN).fake())
}

fn age() -> Property {
    Property::Age(rand::thread_rng().gen_range(0, 100))
}
```

Note that now both functions have the same type signature!

For more information about enums, check the [Rust Book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch06-00-enums.html).

Comment: Thank you very much - as someone who is new to the language, enums are not where I would have looked to support this. I'll go ahead and start reading up on them!